# Canonical name or IP address - socket, linux and C

Tags: c, sockets, berkeley-sockets

How can I know if a `string` is the `canonical name` or the `IP address`?

Because if `argv[1]` is the `IP address` I do:

```
sscanf(argv[2],"%" SCNu16,&server_port);
inet_aton(argv[1],&server_address);

remote_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
remote_address.sin_port = htons(server_port); 
remote_address.sin_addr = server_address;
```

And if argv[1] is the `canonical name` I do:

```
h = gethostbyname(server);

indirizzo_remoto.sin_family = AF_INET;
indirizzo_remoto.sin_port = htons(porta_server); 
indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr = XYZ;
```

Also, what do I have to have in place of `XYZ`?

POSSIBLE SOLUTION:

```
struct in_addr indirizzo_server; 
struct hostent *h; 

h = gethostbyname(server); 

inet_aton(h->h_addr_list[0],&indirizzo_server); 

indirizzo_remoto.sin_family = AF_INET; 
indirizzo_remoto.sin_port = htons(porta_server); 
indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr = indirizzo_server;
```

Comment: just check if it's all digits and periods, e.g. [0-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255]. if it's got any non-digits/non-periods, then it's most likely a hostname.

Comment: Won't getaddrinfo() work with either a host string or an IP address string?

Comment: If you check the digits, you'd have to turn the string into an integer value.  Some canonical names will be in this range even though its not hte correct IP.

Answer (score 3):

Get familiar with [`getaddrinfo(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) that can do either, and also supports IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Why the fuzz? `gethostbyname` already takes care of that. Quoting the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man3/gethostbyname.3.html):

> [...]name is either a hostname, or an IPv4
>          address in standard dot notation (as for inet_addr(3)), or an IPv6
>          address in colon (and possibly dot) notation.

So delete the special handling with `inet_aton` and be done.

Regarding the `XYZ` part: The `hostent` structure contains two things you must copy into your `in_addr`:

- the `h_addrtype` which might indicate IPv4 or IPv6. Copy it into `sin_family`.
- the actual address(es) in `h_add_list`. Copy this into your `sin_addr` using `memcpy` and the length given in `h_length`.

This should both handle IPv4 and IPv6 automatically.

Comment: So, I can do this:                                                     struct in_addr indirizzo_server;                                                    struct hostent *h;                                                     h = gethostbyname(server);                                            inet_aton(h->h_addr_list[0],&indirizzo_server);                                           indirizzo_remoto.sin_family = AF_INET;   
indirizzo_remoto.sin_port = htons(porta_server); 
indirizzo_remoto.sin_addr = indirizzo_server;                         I try now! Thank for now!

Comment: Sorry but It seems to be not formatted. I edit my question so you can read better. See in my question the "POSSIBLE SOLUTION" section.